# socket failed with family not supported in docker environment

Tags: c, sockets, docker, operating-system

I am trying to create a socket as follow but it is failing with error address family not supported. Can any one please help me out as i am beginner to socket.

```
socket(AF_ATMPVC, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

If any other information  is required please let me know in comments.

Comment: Maybe the operating system doesn't have support for "Access to raw ATM PVCs"? What operating system are you on?

Comment: centos 7.5, kernel version 3.10  I would like to tell you that this error coming in docker environment only.

Comment: How about `PF_ATMPVC` Does not work too ?

Comment: It is working fine if i am executing the test case on host os i.e centos7.5, kernel 3.10. But not working in docker coantainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I managed to find an answer for my question. This problem can be fixed by passing `--network=host` option while creating the docker container.
If you use the host network driver for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host.